# Doctrine 2 query returned object has no property or methods

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework 1.11. I have set up my Doctrine intergration and it seams to be working in that, I able to get and instance on an Entity Manager to work with. However, I am baffled by the behaviour of the following line in the controller class:

```
$transfercurrency = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Gesmoney\Entity\Country')->findBy(array('countrycode' => $transfercountry));
```

When I do a var_dump($transfercurrency), I get an object with a whole bunch of properties, infact, it doesn't look right to me. I tried to post it on pastie but it will not let me because its more than 100kb. I therefore just pasted about a quarter of it [enter link description here](http://www.pastie.org/2180504). Also using Netbeans there seem to be no properties or methods for the returned object hence when I invoke code complete I get nothing. When I do var_dump($transfercurrency[0]->id), I get the following error;

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Gesmoney\Entity\Country::$property in
>   /shared/www/dev.gesmoneylatest.com/library/Gesmoney/Entity/Country.php
>   on line 55 NULL

Its quite a long post but I hope someone has the answer to my problem. Thanks.

## Controller class

```
<?php

class Systemadmin_ExchangerateController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
/**
 * @var Bisna\Application\Container\DoctrineContainer
 */
protected $doctrine;

/**
 * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
 */
protected $entityManager;

public function init()
{
    $this->doctrine = Zend_Registry::get('doctrine');
    $this->entityManager = $this->doctrine->getEntityManager();
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
}


public function getexchangerateAction($transfercountry = 'GB') {

    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $transfercurrency = $this->entityManager->getRepository('Gesmoney\Entity      \Country')->findBy(array('countrycode' => $transfercountry));
    var_dump($transfercurrency);
}

}
```

## Entity

```
<?php

 namespace Gesmoney\Entity;
 /**
 * @Entity @Table(name="countries")
 */
 class Country {
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer", length=3, nullable=false) 
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @var integer
 * 
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=25)
 * @var string
 */
private $countryname;

/**
 * @Column(type="datetime")
 * @var string
 */
private $lastupdate;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=2)
 * @var string
 */
private $countrycode;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=20)
 * @var string
 */
private $countrycurrency;

/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=3)
 * @var string
 */
private $currencycode;


/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $property
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Region", mappedBy="country", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $region;


public function __get($property) {
    return $this->property;
}

public function __set($property, $value) {
    $this->property = $value;
}

}
```

## Application.ini excerpt

```
;; added for Doctrine2 Integration
pluginPaths.Bisna_Application_Resource = "Bisna/Application/Resource"

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine Cache Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default cache instance to be used. Optional is only one cache is defined
resources.doctrine.cache.defaultCacheInstance = default

; Cache Instance configuration for "default" cache
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.adapterClass = "Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache"
resources.doctrine.cache.instances.default.namespace    = "Application_"

; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine DBAL Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default connection to be used. Optional if only one connection is defined
resources.doctrine.dbal.defaultConnection = default

; Database configuration
;resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.wrapperClass = ""
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.driver   = "pdo_mysql"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.dbname   = "zzzzz"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.host = "localhost"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.port = zzzz
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.user = "root"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.password = ""


; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Doctrine ORM Configuration
; ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Points to default EntityManager to be used. Optional if only one EntityManager is defined
resources.doctrine.orm.defaultEntityManager = default

; EntityManager configuration for "default" manager
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.connection     = default
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.autoGenerateClasses = true
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.namespace           = "Gesmoney\Entity\Proxy"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.proxy.dir                 = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Gesmoney/Entity/Proxy"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.adapterClass          = "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.mappingNamespace      = "Gesmoney\Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.mappingDirs[]         = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Gesmoney/Entity"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.annotationReaderClass = "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader"
resources.doctrine.orm.entityManagers.default.metadataDrivers.0.annotationReaderCache = default
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `$` on your properties for `__get` and `__set`

```
public function __get($property) {
    return $this->$property;
}

public function __set($property, $value) {
    $this->$property = $value;
}
```